# The logic behind "Call to a member function prepare()"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a function to check for records in my database before executing anything, and i'm getting the error `Call to a member function prepare()` which i don't quite understand. I've been struggeling for quite some time now, and i'd really appriciate some help

The problem should be with the `prepare()` in line 19

```
<?php
$dsn = "xxx"; // Database Source Name
$username="xxx"; // User with acress to database. Root is MySQL admin.
$password="xxx"; //The user password.

try {
  $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  $conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
}

//------------------------ Does the category already exist? -------------------------
function checkuser($fbid,$fbfname,$fblname,$femail) {

$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS subjectcount FROM Users WHERE Fuid=:Fuid";

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":Fuid",$_SESSION['FBID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $subjectcount=$row["subjectcount"];
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Server Error - try again!".$e->getMessage();
    }

//------------------------ If it dosn't, insert it -------------------------
if ($subjectcount==0) {
```

And i'm having a hard time debugging since i dont quite understand the cause of this error.

I updated my code to

```
<?php
$dsn = "xxx"; // Database Source Name
$username="xxx"; // User with acress to database. Root is MySQL admin.
$password="xxx"; //The user password.

try {
  $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  $conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
}

//------------------------ Does the category already exist? -------------------------
function checkuser($fbid,$fbfname,$fblname,$femail) {
global $conn;
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS subjectcount FROM Users WHERE Fuid=:Fuid";

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":Fuid",$_SESSION['FBID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $subjectcount=$row["subjectcount"];
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Server Error - try again!".$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

//------------------------ If it dosn't, insert it -------------------------
if ($subjectcount==0) {
```

Comment: Is this the full error message?

Comment: It's Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/domain/public_html/functions.php on line 19

Comment: I guessed so, and if you had error reporting set to report all errors including notices, then you would have seen the error telling you that `conn` is undefined as well. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the full error message is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

Right?

You are calling the member function (= function which is a member of a class instance) `prepare` of the variable `$conn` which is not declared in the scope of your `checkuser` function, it's declared outside (in global scope)!

To "import" it into your function so you can access it, put this line at the top of your function:

```
global $conn;
```

Also, it looks like you don't have full error reporting enabled, otherwise you would have seen this error before the fatal one, giving you another clue:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn
```

(By the way, you should `exit;` after outputing the DB error message in your `catch` block - otherwise you will print the error but continue to the rest, with a nonexisting DB connection!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer CherryDT. I updated my code ^^